# Php count two words as one

Tags: php

Is possible to count two words as one? I have input tags and i want to count the tags not the words

Code:

```
$name_tags = str_word_count($row['names']); // tag names: "Kevin Alex", "Don John",etc..

<?php  echo number_format($name_tags, 0, '.', ','); ?>
```

Comment: [Why "Is it possible?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270933/should-i-answer-is-it-possible-type-of-questions)

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: If `$row['names']` is an array, you need to use `count($row['names'])` instead

Comment: ^ and if it's not, run `explode()` on it to make it one, then proceed.

Comment: What does `$row['names']` look like? What happens if you print it out. Basically what you need to know is how individual tags are separated.

Comment: "Kevin Alex", "Don John",etc.. in one row are multiple tags

Comment: well, I can tell right away that your db design isn't a good one. You shouldn't be storing comma-separated values, but normalizing your database and looking into relational tables. That way, you could **easily** `COUNT()` them.

Comment: You could split your `$row['names']` into an array and count each array value (name). You should change your design approach now  before you get too far into your code. This approach will just give you constant problems. What if you need a comma separated list which has valid commas in? Use a different delimiter, then you have mixed designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $row['names'] like **Kevin Alex, Don John**

```
$a=explode(",",$row['names']);
echo count($a);
```